# In iOS @synchronized for 2 methods at once?

Tags: ios, multithreading, mutex, synchronized, critical-section

Typically `@synchronized(self)` creates something like critical section.

My problem is I have more than one function which should be accessed with one thread only.

But what will the application do if I write `@synchronized(self)` in each such method? Does it mean one thread can use method1 and other thread can use method2? If no then how to implement it correctly?

Comment: "I have more than one function which should be accessed with one thread only" is this valid statement? i think we can't run two function at a time from single thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@synchronized` attempts to obtain a lock on the object that is passed to it.  If the lock is obtained then execution continues.  If the lock can't be contained then the thread blocks until the lock can be obtained.

The object that you pass to `@synchronized` should be the object that you want to protect from simultaneous updates.  This may be `self` or it may be a property of `self`.  For example, consider the following simple queue implementation:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *qArray;

-(void)append:(id)newObject {
    @synchronized(self.qArray) {
        [self.qArray addObject:newObject];
    }
}

-(id) head {
   id ret=nil;
   @synchronized(self.qArray) {
       if (self.qArray.count >0) {
           ret=self.qArray[0];
           [self.qArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
       }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

In this case `self.qArray` is a good choice for the `@synchronized` as it is the object being modified

Comment: could you explain does `@synchronized(self)` block `self` only or each its mutable object too?

Comment: I guess my answer is a bit confusing when I say "the object you want to protect..." - `@synchronized` doesn't block objects as such, it just blocks a thread until it can obtain a lock where the lock is identified by an object reference. If I had code that accessed/modified qArray  that didn't have an @synchronized block  then that code can still run at the same time as another thread which is in an `@synchronized` block - with possible corruption resulting. You need to be diligent and ensure you use `@synchronized` consistently and  everywhere it is needed

Comment: Should I assume your answer's source code reference to "self.myArray" is a typo or revision mistake, and that it should be "self.qArray"?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Frome someone

The object passed to the `@synchronized` directive is a unique identifier used to distinguish the protected block. If you execute the preceding method in two different threads, passing a different object for the anObj parameter on each thread, each would take its lock and continue processing without being blocked by the other. If you pass the same object in both cases, however, one of the threads would acquire the lock first and the other would block until the first thread completed the critical section.

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)anObj
{

      @synchronized(anObj)
      {
          // Everything between the braces is protected by the @synchronized directive.
      }
}
```

Comment: So if I use `@synchronized(self)` and `self` is a singleton then `self` and all its mutable variables are protected and I don't need to do something extra with this code? Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you access two (or more) functions via one thread. the @synchronized would don't affect your code. because your function is run synchronised without lock help.

Comment: A lot of threads use 2 various methods of one class which work with the same mutable objects but via different ways.

Comment: @synchronized just create a critical section based you passed object, then it block the section code. it don't do block the object you passed.  for example, @synchronized(objA){ objB.element1;}; if two thread access this code, if the objA is same, than the objB can be block protection. but threads can modify the objA's element with thread unsafe.